# Fetching a form associated with a known string literal from a neighbour project using C# windowsforms application

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently I am working with:

C#
Windows forms application

I currently have a problem specifying a domain for my foreach loop
basically I have the string literal of , for example, "TargetForm" and I need to "fetch/get" this TargetForm by name identification and drag it into my other project.

For example

Project A has foreach loop that finds the string and wants to do Application.OpenForms / or whatever works

Project B (GPC) has this form

Is there some way I can get that dynamically? Using any literal domain is not an option as many forms will be added or renamed, I need to get ALL forms in Project B no matter what the users/developers do and match that to the options I give the user in project A.

Any of this make any sense at all? I hope so, if not please help me help you.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The usecase:

The primary project HAS a string value "NameOfTheFormIWantToGet"
The secondary project HAS two partial classes to build a form ( as is tradition )

The action of the matter is an iterator inside project A which uses a string literal to match for a Form object in project B, if there is a match between the string and the name of a form inside the B project, then this question can be considered answered. The rest is already history, it's getting the domain "Look at B for forms" that I can't figure out.

EDIT:

This link I found (after this problem was solved) explains pretty well how you can solve an assembly load target problem with code examples and step by step approach: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_502.asp

Comment: Pls elaborate the usecase, Help us to help you..

Comment: Are you just trying to dynamically get a list of all forms in a project?

Comment: Please explain if you downvote a question so I can help improve it.

Comment: @Daryl, yes, a project outside my current project. It this uses reflection that's fine. It it requires minor filtering or slight overhead then that is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following source searches all types in PrjB.exe and if its a Form it is opened.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly prjB = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\...\PrjB.exe");
            foreach (Type t in prjB.GetTypes())
                if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
                    Form frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                    frm.ShowDialog();
                }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Going to try it right now, if it works I will mark as answered +1 and no longer post here, otherwise I will comment for help.

Comment: This answer is sufficient in combination with my own research and this link http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/instance-name-main-form-t3212818.html. Thank you for your time and effort. It wasn't perfectly accurate for me to use this structure but I will make it from here on outward, this has however left me without the luxury of testing your answer. Let us assume then that others reading this Q&A will have enough information here as I did